# Hebrews 3:13 What is the meaning of while it is called “Today”?

Tags: hebrews

Hebrews 3

> <sup>**12**</sup>Beware, brethren, lest there be in any of you an evil heart of unbelief in departing from the living God; <sup>**13**</sup>but <sup>[b]</sup>exhort one another daily, while it is called “Today,” lest any of you be hardened through the deceitfulness of sin. (NKJV)
> <sub>[b] *encourage*</sub>

Today is of course still today. What is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Greek interlinear, with grammatical notations below.

[image: Hebrews 3:13, Greek Interlinear]

The principal verb "encourage" is listed as being "Present iMperative Active (PMA)," and for second-person plural (you plural).  This verb addresses people in the present; giving directions applicable in the present.  When we afterward see the dependent clause which adds clarification to the original command, it emphasizes the imminence of the expected compliance--"while that it is called today/now."  In other words, don't procrastinate or delay in doing this.  The final clause seems to imply what might happen as the result of a delay: "so that one of you be not hardened through the deceitfulness of sin."

If we delay to encourage someone, putting off for another time, another day, to help them when we know they are hurting or in need of encouragement right now, we may contribute to that person becoming "hardened," or embittered, by sin.

**Conclusion**

The emphasis on "today" and on doing something while the day is still called "today" (i.e., before it becomes "yesterday" or is otherwise in the past) is an important part of the message of this text.  To procrastinate or to delay is to risk one's becoming hardened by sin.